# What are these characters?

Tags: unicode

I'm writing a program that needs to calculate the "size" of a string of characters. The customer provided a table of about a thousand characters and their sizes. The entire table is an image, so I cannot copy and paste text from it. My problem is that I cannot identify four of the characters:

[image: unknown characters]

I drew the characters at https://shapecatcher.com/ but did not find a match. These characters are the only four out of a thousand that didn't have an obvious unicode representation.

Do these characters have a unicode representation, and if so, how do I find it?

Comment: What about if not? See what the image owner suggests or what they can tell about image source detail. Can you not just make something up if that's acceptable ***i.e. right round bracket horizontal scan line, right square bracket horizontal scan line, ..., ...***. Only 4 out of 1000 that are unknown isn't too bad! Perhaps the "unknown" could even be called "unknown" or "TBD", etc.

Comment: Maybe... **`Alchemical symbol for trident: `** or... **`Element of with long horizontal stroke: ⋲`**... probably not but this one is cool **`Cross pommee with half-circle below: `** jack in a bottom half circle... I just made the jack part up!

Answer (score 1):

Could they be standard parentheses and square brackets characters with ["strike-through" attribute](http://mementoprosupport.lumapix.com/support/solutions/articles/12000039351-basic-font-attributes-bold-italics-underline-rotation-skewing-blurring) set, as shown below in LibreOffice *Writer*? (Note that I left it set for the spaces between, too.)

[image: Strike-through characters]

Answer (score 1):

Closest thing I can find is [bracket with quill](https://graphemica.com/%E2%81%85): ⁅, which doesn't match the horizontal line being through the entire bracket as in the picture.

If those are indeed UTF-8 symbols I would expect to also find "parenthesis with quill" to match the bracket.

This might be a situation where it's best to just ask the client for clarification.